# Mysql cli not returning data in bash script run by crontab

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I have a bash script that is executed via a cron job

```
#!/bin/bash

# abort on errors
set -e

ABS_DIR=/path/

# extract the creds for the mysql db
DB_USER="USERNAME"
DB_PASS="PASSWORD"

function extract_data() {
        file=$2
        sql_query=`cat $ABS_DIR/$1`
        data=`mysql -u $DB_USER --password="$DB_PASS" -D "database" -e "$sql_query" | tail -n +2`

        echo -e "Data:"
        echo -e "$data"
}

extract_data "sql_query.sql" "log.csv"
```

When running it manually with `bash extract.sh` the `mysql` cmd fetches the data correctly and I see the `echo -e "$data"` on the console.

When running the script via a cron job

```
* 12 * * * /.../extract.sh > /.../cron_log.txt
```

then I get an empty line saved to the `cron_log.txt` file!?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem; a script behaves differently when run from user shell and when run from crontab.  The cause is typically due to differences in the environment variables in the user shell, and in the crontab shell; by default, they are not the same.

To begin debugging this issue, you could direct stderr as well as stdout from crontab, hopefully to capture an error message:

```
extract.sh &> /.../cron_log.txt
```

(notice the &)

Also: you have three dots (`/.../`) -- that is likely a typo, could also be the cause.

Comment: I've added the output redirect, however, there's no errors returned; the `...` was just a placeholder for the actual path